# What's the word for pictures in a letter that are not attached but rather pasted after the text?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, letter-writing

I am writing a letter with pictures, and I have used before the following sentence: "Please refer to the attached photos."

However, I have been wondering if this is normally used in English when the pictures included in the letter are not attached but rather pasted after the text.

Is there a more conventional way of saying this?

Comment: You mean pasted in an email or stuck in a physical letter?

Comment: Which edge of the paper are these pictures attached to? Does it matter if the photographs or drawings are stapled or taped to the letter instead of pasted or glued to it? What if they were included loose in the same envelope as your letter, no strings attached? What if they were sketched directly onto the same paper as your handwriting, with your words written around them?

Answer (score 4):

"Please refer to the pictures **below**" could work if they are part of the same document.

Comment: And indeed to be found below that reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a zero word answer to the question ... why do you think you need to make specific mention of which bunch of pictures you are referring to?  If I received a letter with pictures pasted into it, printed into it, stapled to it, or simply included in the same envelope, then a sentence, in the letter, such as

*Have a look at the pictures, some of the ones I took on my last trip to Shangri-la*

isn't going to have me wondering which pictures I should be looking for or at. If you want to call attention to particular pictures you might want to scribble numbers on them so you can write

*Picture 6 is the young woman I spent a lot of time with in Shangri-la*

to avoid confusion with the pictures of your sister.

I see no need for *attached* or *pasted* or *included*

Comment: Smooth approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have found a perfect occasion to use precisely this word.

'[Attach](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/attach)':

> *to fasten or affix; join; connect:*
> to attach a photograph to an application with a staple.

For a sense of its historical use, see this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attached%20photo%2Cattached%20photograph%2Cattached%20image&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), showing that the usage of "*attached photograph*" was most common in the 1920's (the use of the word '*photo*' is more modern). [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22attached%20photograph%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1914,cd_max:1935&lr=lang_en) are a few examples, pertaining mostly to documents.

I believe "*included images/photos*" won't necessarily mean they'd be attached or affixed to the letter, rather inserted into the envelope containing the letter.

Comment: Did paste, tape, staples, and paper clips all count for attaching things in the 1920s, and do they all still do so today?

Comment: @tchrist I believe that's beside the point here. The OP has "been wondering if this is normally used in English when the pictures included in the letter are not attached but rather pasted after the text." I'm pointing out that they can be synonymous, in both a literal and a (modern) figurative sense. How do you suggest I improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

"Please refer to the included photos" or "Please see the accompanying photos" would be a more conventional way of saying it if the pictures are pasted after the text.

Another way could be "Please check the photos in the letter" or "The pictures in the letter are referred to in this text."

Answer (score -1):

You could use ***append***. To append something is to add it as a supplement.

"Please refer to the appended photos."

But, as KillingTime suggests, pasted pictures can be described as *attached*. And perhaps your own sentence is more colloquial.